# how to include dynamically in php

Tags: php

Hello I would like to include dynamically in php...

where I could send as parameter the pages that I want, only pages and not the directory ...

was trying as below but did not work:

this is the Loadclassphp.php:

```
<?php
class Loadclass{
public static function load($url)
{   

        foreach($url as $b)
                {
               include "$b.php";
                }


} 
}

?>
```

and here is  where i call:

```
include_once 'Loadclassphp.php'; 
$arr = array(1 => "menu",2 => "client");
Loadclass::load($arr);
```

thanks for the help...

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Did you get an error? Any notices about trying to include non-existing files? Does it sit on the couch all day and eats junk food?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can look into using an autoloader. See reference: http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Essentially, you define a special function that is called everytime a class is to be loaded.
In the function you can define rules and what not, and include the right file.

All you have to do then is do something like `$menu = new $menu($parameters);` and the autoloader will include the file for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script must be in proper directory in order to include the files you passed as an array.

So you must also pass directory if you have to call load multiple times for files that are in different directories. However if all your files always reside in one directory (really bad practice) then you can live off without passing directory.

Here's one way to do it, it will automatically load all php files in the directory, no need to pass arrays...

```
function load_all( $dir )
{
    foreach ( glob($dir.'/*.php') as $filename )
    {
        include $filename;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to include selective files then:

```
function load_all_f( $dir, $files )
{
    foreach ( $files as $filename )
    {
        include $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Don't globally `chdir()` for that... functions _really_ shouldn't effect global stuff like that. Just `include $filename . DIRECTORY_SERPERATOR . $filename;`

Comment: Thanks, was thinking about that :)

Comment: If the passed $dir isn't suffixed with the directory separator (`/` on a real OS and `\ ` on Windows) it won't work well. Add `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` between them, like I suggested in the first comment (but horribly misspelled 'separator' :O)

Answer (score 0):

Your code to load looks like it should work, but you're probably running into a pathfinding issue where the code is in the wrong directory.

But you mention you want *dynamic* includes, this is a solved issue with [`__autoload`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) or [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php):

### here you go

This is my `autoload.inc` file I use to include OOP PHP in 5.3 (which supports namespaces). You have to make sure your directory path structure matches your namespace names (which it should whether or not you're using this autoloader).

```
<?php

function autoload( $class )
{
  require_once( __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace( '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class ) . '.inc');
}

spl_autoload_register( 'autoload' );
```

I used `require_once` because it triggers nice catch-able errors I can turn into `Exceptions` using `set_error_handler`; you can change it to `require`, `include`, or `include_once` if you so choose.

You might also want to change the file-suffix if you don't want to use `.inc` files.

I find that `include('autoload.inc')` is a *lot less boilerplate* than

```
include('Foo.inc');
include('Bar.inc');
include('Baz.inc');
...etc...
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `require_once` - after you include the class, the autoload function won't be called again to load the same class. Also, `[require|include]_once` is slower than `[require|include]` because it has to lookup in the list of previously included files (which can grow quite big) to see if its not there already

Comment: @shesek, good point. I'll keep that in mind when I benchmark.